# SQL server installation

Tags: sql-server-2008, jdbc

I need to connect SQL with JDBC .
My SQL server name is reflecting "PCname/SQLEXPRESS" in SQL studio even if i give default instance during setup
It is "PCname/PCname" if i give name instance with "PCname" during installation

I need to change the SQL server name as "PCname"(instead of PCname/PCname).
How to configure this during installation of SQL.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question is probably more suitable on [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com). Stackoverflow questions are generally programming-related.

Comment: I think you should be able to make your connection without doing a lot of contortions with your database. It's just a matter of getting the right connection string in your code. Check out this very excellent reference -- scroll down for SQL Express tips. http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

Answer (score 0):

if you connect to PCname you are connecting to the default instance of SQL Server
When you install it there is an option to choose between default instance and named instance. Choose default

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't change an instance name or go to/from named to default instance without reinstalling SQL Server.

If you are installing another instance of SQL Server, only one can be the default. If there is already a default instance of SQL Server, setup will not let you install another and will force you to choose an instance name - only one can be the default, all others need to be named instances. How many instances are on your machine?

Why can't JDBC connect to a named instance? Have you looked at the [JDBC documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/)? Or checked out Microsoft support topics such as http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313225 which, even though geared to SQL Server 2000, still have relevance?